# We hope for help my site

Tags: seo

We hope for help
I have a press team, the site does not appear in the top stories, nor does it appear in the first results.
Is it possible to help specialists

Comment: One thing that will help is if your stories are taken up by news aggregators, linking back to your site as the source.